# Regular expression with back reference

Tags: ruby, regex

Can anybody explain how exactly the back reference works in ruby regular expression? I particularly want to know exactly how `(..)` grouping works. For example:

```
s = /(..) [cs]\1/.match("The cat sat in the hat")

puts s
```

for the code snippet above, the output is: `at sat`. Why/How is it getting this output ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is what this regular expression means:

```ruby
regex = /(..) [cs]\1/
#        ├──┘ ├──┘├┘
#        │    │   └─ A reference to whatever was in the first matching group.
#        │    └─ A "character class" matching either "c" or "s".
#        └─ A "matching group" referenced by "\1" containing any two characters.
```

Note that after matching a regular expression with a matching group, the special variables `$1` (`$2`, etc) will contain what matched.

```ruby
/(..) [cs]\1/.match('The cat sat in the hat') # => #<MatchData...>
$1 # => "at"
```

Note also that [the `Regexp#match` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-match) returns a MatchData object, which contains the string which caused the entire match ("at sat", aka `$&`) and then each matching group ("at", aka `$1`):

```ruby
/(..) [cs]\1/.match('The cat sat in the hat')
=> #<MatchData "at sat" 1:"at">
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the output of `puts s` isn't the capture groups:

```
s = /(..) [cs]\1/.match("The cat sat in the hat")
puts s
# at sat
```

If you want to access its capture groups, you should be using `MatchData.captures`:

```
s = /(..) [cs]\1/.match("The cat sat in the hat")
s.captures
# => ["at"]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually, I want to know (..) this grouping means what exactly?

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam: a `.` is a wildcard that matches any char, so `(..)` is a capture group that captures any two chars -- in your case it captures `at`.